# How do i accomplish this animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations

When I enter this website there is a couple of animations to "load" the content.
How do you create this animations? Is there a script plugin or just css keyframes? I dont have that much knowledge about animations on websites but I want to learn :)

Website:  https://melriver.com/

I'm want to learn how to create animation when you enter the website.

I dont know if I should do it by javascript or css keyframs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by JavaScript.
Just use the function of setInterval() it'll do it. It isn't difficult yo build it's just time consuming